# ExFAT formatted SD card not recognizing space

Tags: disk-utility, homebrew, formatting, sd-card

I'm trying to Homebrew my Nintendo Wii, and a 2 GB or under SD card is required. However, the Wii will also recognize 4 GB cards if enough junk is put on it. I'm attempting to do this with my Optima 4GB SD Card (goo.gl/qqJn8p) on Mac OS X, El Capitan (v. 10.11.6). After formatting it to ExFAT, I put a 1.28 GB file on the card. Everything went smoothly. The next time I tried, though, I got an error saying that there wasn't enough space, even though there's plenty left. Here's a screenshot of the SD card info.

[image]

I know that this is a common problem with USB's, but is there any solution for SD cards?

*As a sidenote, I formatted with Disk Utility.

[image]

(ex-post from Stack Overflow)

Comment: What's the partition scheme? If it's GUID, try changing it to MBR.

Comment: The fact that the total capacity shows as being less than the remaining space rings alarm bells. I'd try 2 things; first format it with the official formatter from the SDorg -https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html - then test with Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X) to make sure it's the size it claims to be.

Comment: I've done this before. The Wii doesn't need exFAT. I just used FAT32 or (FAT) with a MBR. Try copying the files again, and it should be fine.

Comment: Just formatted to FAT32 with SDFormatter and checked the card's status with F3X and everything seems to be okay. There's no longer the negative gigabytes in Disk Utility. I noticed that although there are nearly 3 GBs worth of files in the card, it says that there are 2.71 GBs left. After trying to put an 80mb file in it, I got the same error message saying that there wasn't enough space. Image for reference: http://i.imgur.com/prA4ePc.png